# Proof of Sylow by Pinter

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Pinter's proof of the Sylow theorems (p165, part of problem M4), he asks the reader for the following proof. 
Let K be a p-Sylow subgroup of G, and let N(K) be the normalizer of K. Then as part of the proof, one must show that if some element a is in N(K), and the order of the subgroup generated by the coset Ka in N/K is a power of a prime p, then the element a must be in K (i.e., not in N\K).
I cannot see why this is necessarily true.
Also, am I correct in thinking that there can generally be more than one p-Sylow subgroup in a group?

Comment: It's good practice to use latex here.
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this the following way: (I assume it is meant $N=N(K)$)

As $K$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, $p$, by definition, doesn't divide $\vert G:K\vert =\vert G\vert /\vert K\vert $. Now $\vert N\vert /\vert K\vert =\vert N/K\vert $ divides $\vert G:K\vert $ and so $p$ can't divide $\vert N/K\vert $ either. So there is no element with order a power of $p$ in $N/K$, except $[1]$.
So if $[a]\in N/K$ (where $[a]$ shall denote the class $Ka$, as for $[1]$ above) has as order a power of $p$, for an $a\in N$, then $[a]=[1]$, which means $a\in K$.

And, you are right: there can be several $p$-Sylow subgroups for a given group $G$ and a given $p$, but they are all conjugate (and thus isomorphic) to each other (which is actually one of the Sylow theorems)

Kind regards!

Comment: Thanks.  Two questions: Does your first statement concerning the non-divisibility by p follow from the fact that K is maximal in terms of group inclusion?  Secondly, (assuming you have access to the Pinter text), he indicates in the same problem that S* = K.  But S* and S depend on which element a of N(K) you choose, whereas K does not.  So this does not seem correct.  Does he mean the union of all S and S* over all a?

Comment: You're welcome. For your first question: You're right, a $p$-Sylow group $K$ in $G$ is defined to be a *maximal* $p$-subgroup of $G$, which means exactly that $p$ doesn't divide $\vert G:K\vert $. For your second question: Unfortunately i have no acces to the text at the moment -- if you however described the problem to me (e.g. as an edit of your original question) i would definitely see what i can do...